# About how often does a mohel say Tachanun?

Tags: brit-milah, tachanun

When a *mohel* is present in shul, no one in the minyan needs to recite *Tachanun*.

If any reader is a mohel or otherwise would know how to answer this question, "fairly", I'm curious how often the mohel, himself, says *Tachanun*. Or, is it more common for the mohel to go to a minyan elsewhere where he's *not* doing a *brit*, prior to coming to the other shul where he **will** be doing the brit?

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. The mohel doesn't say Tachanun that morning independent of where the bris will be

Comment: @DoubleAA I.e., if a mohel appears in a minyan where no brit will occur, I assume that he would say tachanun, there. It's not the fact that he is a mohel, but the fact that there is a brit that would cancel Tachanun. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I don't think that's true. But anyway, that means you're asking how often mohalim daven somewhere else? Why is that interesting at all to anyone? Clearly it will vary based on the mohel's schedule, location, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason I explained [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91022/16354) (namely that the day of a Bris Milah is a Yom Tov for the Mohel), a Mohel does not say Tachanun for Shacharis no matter where he davens in the morning.

From my experience (and I believe the Halacha follows this), he exempts all of those davening in the Minyan from Tachanun as well.  It is actually a common practice around the world at early, quick Minyanim for a Mohel to Daven there and the Minyan will skip Tachanun any day the Mohel will be doing a Bris later.  I'm sure others have seen this as well, feel free to chime in in the comments.)