# Does a mohel say Tachanun during mincha if he did a brit in the morning?

Tags: brit-milah, mincha-afternoon-prayer

In a shul where a mohel is present for a brit, he (nor others in the minyan) say *Tachanun*. Usually, a brit is done after *Shacharit*.

Someone (not a mohel) told me, recently, that when a mohel has doen a brit in the morning, he is exempt from saying *Tachanun* during mincha, regardless of which shul he attends (i.e., even if not doing a brit at mincha.) I haven't been able to locate a source to support this. Is this halacha or a minhag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard this as well, because it is considered a Yom Tov for the Baalei Habris (the father and Sandik are also exempt, IIRC). This halacha is brought [here](http://www.dat-rehovot.co.il/%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%A8%D7%91/item/167-%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D.html) from the Halacha Berura, although I believe it has earlier sources as well.

Edit:  The concept of it being a Yom Tov for the Baalei Habris can be found in the [Rema OC 135:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.135.1?vhe=Wikisource_Shulchan_Aruch&lang=bi), and there are a number of other early sources as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Rema 131:4:](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.4?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en):

נהגו שלא ליפול על פניהם לא בבית האבל ולא בבית החתן ולא בב"ה ביום מילה ולא כשיש שם חתן:‏
 **הגה** ודוקא שהמילה או החתן באותו ב"ה אבל אם אין המילה בב"ה אע"פ שהיא בב"ה האחרת אומרים תחנון (פסקי מהרי"א סימן פ"א) וביום המילה שאין אומרים תחנון דוקא שחרית שמלין אז התינוק אבל במנחה אף על פי שמתפללין אצל התינוק הנימול אומרים תחנון מה שאין כן בחתן שאין אומרים תחנון כל היום כשמתפללין אצל החתן (הגהות מיי' פ"ה מה"ת) ולא מקרי חתן אלא ביום שנכנס לחופה:‏

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 22:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.22.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> אֵין אוֹמְרִים תַּחֲנוּן בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם מִילָה, אוֹ שֶׁהַבַּעַל בְּרִית אוֹ הַסַּנְדָּק, אוֹ הַמּוֹהֵל מִתְפַּלְּלִים שָׁם, אַף שֶׁהַמִּילָה תְּהֵא בְּבַיִת אַחֵר. וְאִם מִתְפַּלְּלִין מִנְחָה, בְּבֵית הַתִּינוֹק קוֹדֵם סְעֻדַּת הַבְּרִית, אוֹ בְּאֶמְצַע הַסְּעֻדָּה, גַּם כֵּן אֵין אוֹמְרִים. אֲבָל אִם מִתְפַּלְּלִים לְאַחַר בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, אוֹמְרִים. אַךְ הַבַּעַל בְּרִית וְהַסַּנְדָּק וְהַמּוֹהֵל לֹא יֹאמְרוּ אַף לְאַחַר בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, מִשּׁוּם דְּיוֹם טוֹב שֶׁלָּהֶם הוּא‏‏
>
> Tachanun is omitted in a synagogue where a circumcision will take place, or if the father of the child to be circumcised, or the sandik who holds the child at the circumcision; or the mohel5 is praying there, even if the circumcision will take place at another location. If the minchah prayer is said, in the child's home, before the bris feast or during the feast [there,] too, [tachanun] is omitted. But, if [the mincha] prayer is said after birkas hamazon [tachanun] is said. However, the father of the child, the one holding the child and the mohel do not say [tachanun] even after birkas hamazon because it is their holiday.