# Difference between Shacharis and Mincha re:Tachanun if Sandek/Mohel/father is present

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, brit-milah, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If a Sandek, or Mohel or father-of-the-baby are present during Shacharis, then the entire congregation skip Tachanun.

If, however, they are present at Mincha, then these individuals do not say Tachanun, but the congregation does. (Unless Mincha is being prayed before or during the Seudath Miztva of the Bris - according to the Kitzur.)

What is the difference between Shacharis and Mincha?

Sources: [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 22:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.22.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> אֵין אוֹמְרִים תַּחֲנוּן בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם מִילָה, אוֹ שֶׁהַבַּעַל בְּרִית אוֹ הַסַּנְדָּק, אוֹ הַמּוֹהֵל מִתְפַּלְּלִים שָׁם, אַף שֶׁהַמִּילָה תְּהֵא בְּבַיִת אַחֵר. וְאִם מִתְפַּלְּלִין מִנְחָה, בְּבֵית הַתִּינוֹק קוֹדֵם סְעֻדַּת הַבְּרִית, אוֹ בְּאֶמְצַע הַסְּעֻדָּה, גַּם כֵּן אֵין אוֹמְרִים. אֲבָל אִם מִתְפַּלְּלִים לְאַחַר בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, אוֹמְרִים. אַךְ הַבַּעַל בְּרִית וְהַסַּנְדָּק וְהַמּוֹהֵל לֹא יֹאמְרוּ אַף לְאַחַר בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, מִשּׁוּם דְּיוֹם טוֹב שֶׁלָּהֶם הוּא‏
>
> Tachanun is omitted in a synagogue where a circumcision will take place, or if the father of the child to be circumcised, or the sandik who holds the child at the circumcision; or the mohel5 is praying there, even if the circumcision will take place at another location. If the minchah prayer is said, in the child's home, before the bris feast or during the feast [there,] too, [tachanun] is omitted. But, if [the mincha] prayer is said after birkas hamazon [tachanun] is said. However, the father of the child, the one holding the child and the mohel do not say [tachanun] even after birkas hamazon because it is their holiday.

[Shulchan Aruch - Orach Chaim 131:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.4?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)

> נהגו שלא ליפול על פניהם לא בבית האבל ולא בבית החתן ולא בב"ה ביום מילה ולא כשיש שם חתן:‏
> **הגה** ודוקא שהמילה או החתן באותו ב"ה אבל אם אין המילה בב"ה אע"פ שהיא בב"ה האחרת אומרים תחנון (פסקי מהרי"א סימן פ"א) וביום המילה שאין אומרים תחנון דוקא שחרית שמלין אז התינוק אבל במנחה אף על פי שמתפללין אצל התינוק הנימול אומרים תחנון מה שאין כן בחתן שאין אומרים תחנון כל היום כשמתפללין אצל החתן (הגהות מיי' פ"ה מה"ת) ולא מקרי חתן אלא ביום שנכנס לחופה:‏

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91020/501

Comment: Isn't the difference clearly whether or not the bris happened yet?

Comment: @DoubleAA - let's assume that - so why does the Sandek not say Tachanun but the other members of the Minyan do say it? What "power" does he have at Shacharis that he no longer has at Mincha?

Comment: The day of... is the case, not the half day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that in all times until recently the Brit was done in the shul right before Alenu Lashabe'ach. To this day we say Alenu  Lashabe'ach after every Brit - and that is to be the reason.

So Halacha books assume that the Brit was in the morning in the shul and then the entire shul was participating of the Miztva so nobody said Tachanoon.

But at Mincha there is not to be a Brit. However,  if they are in middle of the meal then all are participating in Mitzva.

So no power to the Moel or father. In morning everybody is a Bal Simcha, in the afternoon after meal nobody is Bal Simcha anymore except the Moel and father who are celebrating happy event all day.